# What charting js library does salesforce's analytics?

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, charts

I was wondering if anyone could identify what charting/graphing library salesforce's analytics uses for their site.

https://www.salesforce.com/analytics-playground/wave/explore.html?app=onboarddash#dashboard/99000000011

Not sure if it's D3, or something in-house.

Comment: Ask them :). I don't recognise anything other than React, but there may be something built with something else thats hard to spot. If you ask them politely saying you love their work, and can you give some tip about any lib used, or was it all in house, and you may be surprised.

Answer (score 1):

This is a custom chart widget built with `react`, `backbone` and `underscore`. I'm not sure if not obfuscated code is abailable.

Answer (score 0):

It is 100% written from scratch ground up, and yes, it does leverage React and HTML5 Canvas, or in the case of the mobile app, the JavaScript scene graph is rendered natively using OpenGL.